# Looking for an interface for numerous video files

Tags: lineageos, file-management, media-player, media-files, vlc

I'm using VLC on LineageOS, to browse and play files (audio or video) in folders that can have hundreds of items.

The LineageOS native file manager doesn't let me play some files (notably, Opus), thus I open my files with the VLC file browser. But it has 2 caveats:

- The view isn't very compact, so I see only a small part of file names.
- When there are hundreds of video files in the folder, VLC starts generating thumbnails for these, with is a very, very long task, and once such a task has begun, VLC hangs when I try to open any file...

Therefore, I'm looking for the following solutions:

- Tweaking VLC for a more compact files view, and even more importantly, disabling thumbnails generation.
- Finding an alternate file manager that doesn't have the above issues, and let me open my files (mkv, mp4, webm, opus, m4a). As a bonus, I'd really enjoy a file filter so I can search for files with specific words in the name.

I guess the VLC configuration isn't doable (but it would be so great!), so I guess I'm looking for a new file manager that will fulfil my above needs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the videos stored in the internal memory ("sd-card" section) or are they stored on a physical sd-card? For the latter the access is a bit more complicated which is the reason that some videos may fail. Anyway VLC is a bit buggy in this scenario. Try MXPlayer to check if it is the file manager or the video player.

Comment: Try MX player, according to me, it is better than VLC with much flexibility.

Comment: I've tried MX Player very quickly, so far it seems great. Filenames are displayed on multiple lines so I can see the full names, and thumbnails are generated very quickly and there doesn't seem to be hanging issues.